# How to check shared library version in the binary

Tags: c, linux, unix, shared-libraries

I have a program that is linked with some shared library on start. There are multiple versions of the library installed on the host. Is there some function or macro that can check the version of library that was linked to my program? I want something like this:

```
int main() {
    REQUIRE_LIBRARY_VERSION_GREATER("libgcc", 1, 2, 3); //example
}
```

Is it possible in unix? I need it at least on linux and freebsd.

EDIT: I would prefer to avoid fork/exec if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [dl_iterate_phdr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dl_iterate_phdr) function  to find out which shared objects are loaded. This is example of dl handler that prints shared libs info

```
static int header_handler(struct dl_phdr_info* info, size_t size, void* data)
{
    printf("name=%s (%d segments) address=%p\n",
            info->dlpi_name, info->dlpi_phnum, (void*)info->dlpi_addr);
    for (int j = 0; j < info->dlpi_phnum; j++) {
         printf("\t\t header %2d: address=%10p\n", j,
             (void*) (info->dlpi_addr + info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_vaddr));
         printf("\t\t\t type=%u, flags=0x%X\n",
                 info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_type, info->dlpi_phdr[j].p_flags);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

It is taken from [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/25/load-time-relocation-of-shared-libraries/)

It prints for my video processing project following :

```
name=/usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4 (7 segments) address=0x7f467935a000
name=/usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4 (7 segments) address=0x7f46796e9000
...
```

Opencv includes the version in the name of library libopencv_imgproc.so***.2.4*** .
This way i know wich opencv version loaded. I don't know if it is good for your libraries, but it can be a starting point for your.

Comment: It looks like this might work. I give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ldd command list shared libraries for your executable

```
ldd <executable>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need some function or macro to call from my program, not from console.